# Unable to change margin

Tags: html, css

So I have been working on this [***WEBSITE***](http://shanebacon.com) and as you can tell the text is slightly moved down (If you have a big enough screen if not pictures are at bottom)

I'd like for the text to be moved up more (like Image at bottom) I've tried all kinds of things from padding to margins of everything. Please enlighten me on what I am doing wrong.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="container">

  <div id="indexmenu">

      <nav id="indexnav" class="navigation">

            <ul>
                <li class="first" class="active"><a href="#"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h1>SB</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://bettercontactform.com/contact/media/8/8/88c85a06189116122cb1d4a0236502eff8dbb78e.js" rel="contactus">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>

<footer>
    <p>Designed with <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span> <a href="/">ShaneBacon</a> 2015 </p>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

Apparently stackoverflow does not like my css formatting so heres a paste bin

[**Click**](http://pastebin.com/MZx2r5zj)

**What I want it to look like(general idea):**
[image: What I'd like it to look like]

**What it really looks like**
[image: The Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<h1>` head (SB) has a font-size of 300px, and the bootstrap library is giving it a lineheight of 330px, and its default vertical align is baseline, but the blue 'container' is 200px high. The text will overflow outside of the blue area and HTML flow is down (Meaning its not going to overflow up, like you're wanting the top of the SB to). I would try changing the line-height of the h1 to the same of the container (i.e. 200px) and you may get something closer to what you are wanting, or you may have to use relative positioning to move the text 'up'.

Answer (score 1):

There could be more going on, but you have two opening div's and only one closing div. This is going to cause issues in terms of styling.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out even though it was not the initial problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `CSS` you will be requiring in order to do what you are intending.

Solution: [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/NNsC4vnc)

Adjust the paddings according to screen sizes.